CollectionView control in a MAUI .net 9 app only fires load more items command once when supporting increment load
I am using a CollectionView component in a page and loading data incrementally to support large list of items.
Here is the view XAML:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<localPages:ContentPageBase xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MyNamespace.Pages.MyPage"
             xmlns:localPages="clr-namespace:MyNamespace.Pages"
             xmlns:localViewModels="clr-namespace:MyNamespace.ViewModels"
             xmlns:localModels="clr-namespace:MyNamespace.Providers.Models"
             x:DataType="localViewModels:MyViewModel">
    <Grid Padding="10,10">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="300" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Grid Grid.Row="0" ColumnDefinitions="*,Auto"
              HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <Label x:Name="TitleLabel"
                   Grid.Column="0"
                   FontAttributes="Bold"
                   Text="Live TV"
                   HorizontalOptions="Start"
                   VerticalOptions="Center"/>
            <Label Grid.Column="1"
                   HorizontalOptions="End"
                   VerticalOptions="Center"
                   Text="{Binding TotalCategoriesCount, StringFormat='({0:N0} Categories)'}" />
        </Grid>

        <!-- Categories Collection -->
        <RefreshView Grid.Row="1"
                     IsRefreshing="{Binding IsRefreshing}"
                     Command="{Binding RefreshCommand}">
            <CollectionView x:Name="CategoriesCollection"
                            Grid.Row="1"
                            SelectionMode="Single"
                            ItemsSource="{Binding Categories}"
                            ItemSizingStrategy="MeasureFirstItem"
                            RemainingItemsThreshold="10"
                            RemainingItemsThresholdReachedCommand="{Binding LoadMoreCategoriesCommand}"
                            ItemsUpdatingScrollMode="KeepScrollOffset"
                            SelectionChanged="CategoriesCollection_SelectionChanged"
                            EmptyView="No categories">
                <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                    <GridItemsLayout Orientation="Vertical" />
                </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate x:DataType="localModels:ICategoryInfo">
                        <Border Stroke="DarkGray">
                            <Border.StrokeShape>
                                <RoundRectangle CornerRadius="5,5,5,5" />
                            </Border.StrokeShape>
                            <Grid HeightRequest="40">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Label Text="{Binding Name}"
                                       Padding="5,0,5,0"
                                       FontAttributes="Bold"
                                       VerticalTextAlignment="Center"/>
                                <Label Text="{Binding ID}" Grid.Column="1"
                                       Padding="5,0,5,0"
                                       FontAttributes="Bold"
                                       VerticalTextAlignment="Center"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            </CollectionView>
        </RefreshView>
    </Grid>
</localPages:ContentPageBase>

And here is my ViewModel class:
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Windows.Input;
using MyNamespace.Models;

namespace MyNamespace.ViewModels
{
    internal class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private const int _CategoriesToFetchPerRequest = 100;

        private bool _isRefreshing;
        private int _totalCategoiesCount;

        public MyViewModel()
        {
            // Initialize data loading
            RefreshCommand.Execute(null);
        }

        public ObservableCollection<ICategoryInfo> Categories { get; } = new();

        public int TotalCategoriesCount
        {
            get => _totalCategoiesCount;
            private set
            {
                if (_totalCategoiesCount != value)
                {
                    _totalCategoiesCount = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }

        public bool IsRefreshing
        {
            get => _isRefreshing;
            private set
            {
                if (_isRefreshing != value)
                {
                    _isRefreshing = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }

        public ICommand RefreshCommand => new Command(async () => await RefreshAsync());

        public ICommand LoadMoreCategoriesCommand => new Command(async () => await LoadMoreCategoriesAsync());

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        private async Task RefreshAsync()
        {
            if (IsRefreshing)
                return;
            IsRefreshing = true;
            try
            {
                // Fetch the categories here
                var categories = ...;
                // Determine total count
                var totalCategories = ...;

                Categories.Clear();
                foreach (var category in categories)
                     Categories.Add(new CategoryInfo() { ID = Categories.Count, Name = category. Name });
                    
                TotalCategoriesCount = totalCategores;
            }
            finally
            {
                IsRefreshing = false;
            }
        }

        private async Task LoadMoreCategoriesAsync()
        {
            if (IsRefreshing)
                return;
            IsRefreshing = true;
            try
            {
                // Fetch the next set of categories here
                var categories = ...;

                foreach (var category in categories)
                     Categories.Add(new CategoryInfo() { ID = Categories.Count, Name = category. Name });
            }
            finally
            {
                IsRefreshing = false;
            }
        }
    }
}


The collection view works as follows:

Loads the initial set of categories.
When I scroll to the bottom of the collection, it fires the LoadMoreCategories command and loads the next page adding to the list of items in the collection as expected.
When I keep scrolling down the end of the updated collection list, it never fires the LoadMoreCategories command again to get the next set of categories.

Does anyone know why this may be happening? What am I doing wrong here?

I find it strange that people get all paranoid about using "async void"; and will instead tie up event handlers awaiting a task; thereby making the whole thing synchronous anyway. It implies a lack of confidence in the understanding of a given application when blindly applying "async task" in every case.

@GerrySchmitz Are you referring to "async Task" return type in my Refresh and LoadMoreCategories methods? I did not include the actual full logic in the pasted code that actually makes a REST API call in both of those methods. Those nested calls are asynchronous and hence the return type. But if there is any issue with my code above, assuming that my actual code contains longer body for those methods, please let me know. Would love to learn more. :-) Thanks.

Please debug the LoadMoreCategoriesAsync, check categories, and check if there is any data increment in Categories.

A task is either "fire and forget" (making it truely async); or it isn't. Using void means it will not "await" the rest of the method. If your task is invoked via an event which is subscribed to by who knows who else, what does "awaiting" that event do for whatever is supposed follow that event? If they have to "wait", then your async is not async after all. The point of Observable collections is that another "task" can quietly load it in the "background"; which is not the case if you're "awaiting" that "loading task".

Hi @liyu, the LoadMoreCategoriesAsync method does not even get invoked after the first call. That is what I am trying to figure out what am I doing wrong in the first invocation that might be causing the CollectionView to never fire it again when it reaches the end of the currently loaded items. Thanks.

Why do not use the BindingContext = new MyViewModel() ? @BSingh
